# Get date with Sequalize operators

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I need to get records from DB where event date is in 3 days after today. Date format is `2019-07-06 12:00:00` For example if today is 4th of July - Sequalize should return all records with field `event` equals any time on 7th July.

My asumption to use Sequalize operator. Moment lib is available in scope so probably it will helps.

```
const records = await this.bookingService.findAll({
      where: {
        event: { [this.sequelize.Op.eq]: moment().add(3, 'days').toDate() }
      }
    });
```

At generall I like this idea, but it doesn't show any records as they have a different time. Maybe i need to format event field from DB but have no ideas how to get acces to `event` field in this row `event: { [this.sequelize.Op.eq]: moment().add(3, 'days').toDate() }`

Answer (score 0):

Well I've find solution. Actually I don't need to format event date, instead i need to create two timestamps at start and end of day in 3 days. Like this:

`const startDate = moment().add(3, 'days').startOf('day').format()`
`const endDate = moment().add(3, 'days').endOf('day').format()`

than just check if record event field is in range of this dates:

```
const records = await this.bookingService.findAll({
      where: {
        event: { [this.sequelize.Op.between]: [startDate, endDate]}
      }
    });
```